# Need to get MUI multi select checkbox checked value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using this mui multi [select](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/#checkmarks) and need to know if the item is selected or unselected to set the right state value.I checked `event.target` but there doesnt seem to be a `checked` literal

This is my mui code

```
<FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 300 }}>
    <InputLabel id="demo-multiple-checkbox-label">Tag</InputLabel>
    <Select
      labelId="demo-multiple-checkbox-label"
      id="demo-multiple-checkbox"
      multiple
      value={selectedVal}
      onChange={handleChange}
      input={<OutlinedInput label="Tag" />}
      renderValue={(selected) => selected.join(", ")}
      MenuProps={MenuProps}
    >
      {console.log(data)}
      {data.length > 0 ? (
        data.map((obj) => (
          <MenuItem
            key={obj.label + obj.accountNumber}
            value={obj.accountNumber ? obj.accountNumber : obj.label}
          >
            <Checkbox checked={selectedVal.indexOf(obj.label) > -1} />
            <ListItemText primary={obj.label} />
          </MenuItem>
        ))
      ) : (
        <MenuItem>None</MenuItem>
      )}
    </Select>
  </FormControl>
```

This is my change handler

```
  const handleChange = (event) => {
const {
  target: { value },
} = event;
console.log("value");
console.log(event["target"].checked);
setSelectedVal(
  // On autofill we get a stringified value.
  typeof value === "string" ? value.split(",") : value
);
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to assume that the `event` your change handler gets is a standard browser DOM event.  It is not.  It is an MUI event object of type  `SelectChangeEvent` and it will have the properties of that object.

See the code examples in [this section of the MUI docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/#multiple-select).  In particular I find the code of the "Checkmarks" TypeScript example to be quite informative.

Comment: Yes, I understand its not the default event, I looked at the content of the event and nothing stood out. I am looking for alternative solutions or maybe if I missed something. I looked at the TS code and it didnt tell me more than the JS one

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a consistent `value`. In MenuItem you are using the below logic.

```
value={obj.accountNumber ? obj.accountNumber : obj.label}
```

But in Checkbox you are checking if its checked based on

```
checked={selectedVal.indexOf(obj.label) > -1}
```

Try to keep the `value` consistent in both MenuItem and Checkbox.

```
{data.length > 0 ? (
  data.map((obj) => {
    const value = obj.accountNumber ? obj.accountNumber : obj.label;
    return <MenuItem
      key={obj.label + obj.accountNumber}
      value={value}
    >
      <Checkbox checked={selectedVal.indexOf(value) > -1} />
      <ListItemText primary={obj.label} />
    </MenuItem>
  })
) : (
  <MenuItem>None</MenuItem>
)}
```